# How to migrate in Laravel after changing string everywhere in the database

Tags: php, laravel, database-migration

I had a task from my clients to change the name of a feature everywhere in the site, routes, and all mentions in the database.

Let's say I wanted to replace 'foo' with 'bar' everywhere.

So I found all the mentions of 'foo' in all the columns of all database tables using phpMyAdmin's search feature. Turns out the word appears in 3 different columns, all in the `cm_content` table.

So I did the following to update all the mentions:

```
UPDATE cm_content SET text1 = REPLACE(text1, 'foo', 'bar');
UPDATE cm_content SET text2 = REPLACE(text2, 'foo', 'bar');
UPDATE cm_content SET text3 = REPLACE(text3, 'foo', 'bar');
```

My question is, seeing how this is a local change, how do I migrate these changes to production in a reversible manner? Obviously I can manually run these queries after uploading the updated code, and write queries that I can manually run to reverse the effect if need be.

But, I am looking for a way to use migration/seeds for this and I'm struggling because this sort of change is unorthodox and doesn't seem to quite fit into the scope of the usual tools.

Comment: Adding it to a migration is fairly easy, with `DB::statement()`. However, rolling it back may be a bit more difficult. You can switch the strings around, but there's no guarantee that you're not changing more than you expect.

Answer (score -1):

Simply you can initiate route and put this code inside a method, call it in production